# C# string pairing method (external file)

Tags: c#, .net

I’m writing a windows service C# service.

Within it I need a piece of functionality that can take a value (string) and look to an external file to try and match it and return the matching value, also a string.
So for example, the file might have:

```
Stringone – anothertwo
```

So if Stringone was passed the return value would be anothertwo
I need to it to be quite quick and importantly I must be able to make changes without having the recompile, so putting it into the resource file is not really an option.

Going to be less than 100 entries.  So DB seems overkill.

Does anyone have some suggestions of what might be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think a Dicitionary<string, string> helps.

Comment: A resource file seems like a very reasonable solution. You don't have to compile resource files, they can say as independent files (much like app.config).

Comment: But that would require a recomplile for any changes would it not?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try XML or JSON? Create Serializable class.

Like

```
public class Entries
{
[JsonMember]
 public string key{get;set;}
[JsonMember]
public string value{get;set;}
}
```

and use its collection to read.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a very small amount of entries, I think the easiest thing would be to create a `dictionary<string, string>`, serialize to json (since it's simple), and in the `start` method of the service just deserialize it.
Then, when your service gets a request, all you have to do is something like this:

```
public string GetTranslation(string source)
{
    string returnValue = "";
    _Dictionary.TryGetValue(source, out returnValue);
    return returnValue; // if TryGetValue fails, you simply return an empty string
}
```

Or, you can return the source if there is no translation:

```
public string GetTranslation(string source)
{
    string returnValue = "";
    return _Dictionary.TryGetValue(source, out returnValue) ? source, returnValue;
}
```

Either way it's going to be super quick.